# What is the difference between DropDownList and DropDownListFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, helper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between DropDownlist or DropDownListFor Html helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182280/difference-between-dropdownlist-or-dropdownlistfor-html-helper)

I'm new in `asp.net` `mvc` and `.net`. In general my programming background in PHP.

What is the difference between `DropDownList` and `DropDownListFor`? Why the `For` ?

Where I can find a definition for every one of this helpers and an example to understand how to use it?

Comment: question is not about only dropdownlist. He ask difference between strongly typed and others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic difference includes:

```
DropdownList                              DropDownListFor
- weakly typed(runtime time checking    -strongly typed(compile time checking)
- support since mvc 1                    -supports from mvc 2
-do not support lambda expression to     -supports
     specify id/name of element         
- need to hardcode the id/name           -simply specifying via viewmodel with the help of lambda expression            
  of element
```

Answer (score 0):

You should researc strongly typed Html Helpers.

This is an example of them : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In short lay-mans terms the Html Helpers with "For" at the end expect you to pass a model/viewmodel  - in essence mvc will do the plumbing, naming and repopulating of the model for you.

The non-For helpers of the same name are for when you want to construct the tag using declarative syntax in an ad-hoc (non model related fashion) i.e. you're going to type the id/name of the control as a parameter + other info directly into the helper method params and you are taking responsibility for providing the info and finding the values again when a post back occurs.