# MVC .NET Create Drop Down List from Model Collection in Strongly Typed view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

So I have a view typed with a collection like so:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IList<DTO.OrganizationDTO>>" %>
```

The OrganizationDTO looks like this:

```
public OrganizationDTO
{
    int orgID { get; set; }
    string orgName { get; set; }
}
```

I simply want to create a Drop Down List from the collection of OrganizationDTO's using an HTML helper but for the life of me I cant figure it out! Am I going about this the wrong way?

Should I be using a foreach loop to create the select box?

Comment: Well, I am trying to use <%= Html.DropDownListFor() %> but I am not sure thats the right thing to do.

Comment: It's absolutely the right thing to do.  I ask again, what specifically have tried?  We can't help you if you don't show us the code you're using.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did a small example, with a model like yours:

```
public class OrganizationDTO
{
    public int orgID { get; set; }
    public string orgName { get; set; }
}
```

and a Controller like:

```
public class Default1Controller : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Default1/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IList<OrganizationDTO> list = new List<OrganizationDTO>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new OrganizationDTO { orgID = i, orgName = "Org " + i });
        }

        return View(list);
    }

}
```

and in the view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.First().orgID, new SelectList(Model.AsEnumerable(), "orgId","orgName")) %>
```

Comment: Ahh. This looks like what I need. The first part was throwing me off because m is a collection and I was getting lost cause m => m.orgID didnt exist.

Comment: So according to the Answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182280/difference-between-dropdownlist-or-dropdownlistfor-html-helper) the DropDownListFor seems to be the better option since its strongly typed so I gotta give the credit to this answer. Thank you!

Comment: @ColinPear Be careful with `m.First().orgID`, it will throw error if list is empty.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("SomeName", new SelectList(Model, "orgID", "orgName"), "Please select Organization") %>
```

Comment: Thanks, very simple way.