# MVC create dropdownlist with static elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I create a simple dropdownlist with static elements(hardcoded) using MVC?

That would look like this:

```
   <select name="type_ins">
            <option value="1">First</option>
            <option value="2">Second</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: What programming language or framework are you using?

Comment: When you are programming with ASP.NET MVC..

Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576257/bind-html-dropdownlist-with-static-items

Comment: What's wrong with the code you already typed? Perhaps you are really asking how to pass the selection back to the controller, ie how to map it to an action parameter ?

Answer (score 2):

check below code

```
Html.DropDownList(
    string name,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    string optionLabel,
    object htmlAttributes) 



List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
items.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
          Text = "Swimming",
          Value = "1"
        });
items.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Cycling",
            Value = "2",
            Selected = true
        });
items.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Running",
            Value = "3"
        });
```

Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734782/mvc-net-create-drop-down-list-from-model-collection-in-strongly-typed-view)

Answer (score 0):

In  Model

```
public class DemoModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Test 1" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Test 2" },

            };
        }
    }
}
```

In Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new DemoModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

In View

```
@model DemoModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Values)
```