# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'PestType'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

I am learning MVC and Entity Framework, so pleas bear my questions... I am trying to create a drop down menu for a property (Enum type) for my model class SinglePest
Here is the model:

```
public class SinglePest
{
    public int SinglePestId { get; set; }
    public PestType PestType { get; set; } // here is my problem
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string  TechName { get; set; }
    public string Markings { get; set; }

    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public SourceType SourceType { get; set; }

    //virtual property
    public Source Source { get; set; }
}
```

Here is PestType:

```
    public enum PestType
{
    Dog,
    Cat,
    Fox,
    Rabbit,
    Rat
}
```

This is the controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create (//(SinglePest singlepest)
    [Bind(Include= "Alias, TechName, SerialNumber, PestType, Markings")] SinglePest singlepest)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.SinglePests.Add(singlepest);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (DataException /* dex */)
        {

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes, try again, if problem   persits contact your administrator");
        }

        //ViewBag.SerialNumber = new SelectList(db.Sources, "SerialNumber", "SerialNumber", singlepest.SerialNumber);
        return View(singlepest);
    }
```

And here is the View where I get the error (There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'PestType'.) :

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PestType, "Pest Type")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("PestType", String.Empty) // here is the error
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PestType.ToString())
    </div>
```

Now I have seen some posts about displaying enum, but I can't figure out a solution for my problem. Could please someone give me some piece of advice on how to fix it?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What does `PestType` contain? have you overridden `ToString()` in this class?

Comment: No I haven't `PestType` contains just the enum. Pestype is not a proper class... I'll edit the question

Comment: out of curiosity was that supposed to be `PetType` (type of animal) or `PestType` (type of nuisance)?

Comment: It should be `PestType`...the project I am working on is a feral pest tracking system, and in the specs the animal are called pests. I figured to call my class pest. I am not native speaker so sometimes I mess up with names

Comment: I built a mockup, as the problem seems far simpler than the answers indicated, and have added it below with a simpler solution. You are just missing a `ViewBag.PestType` list in your controller's `Create` methods, which you can create from the `PestType` Enum as christiandev suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `@Html.DropDownList("PestType", String.Empty)`, but the second param needs to be an `IEnumerable<T>`.  You will need the list of your pest in the model, and then use `model.Pests` for example where Pets is an `IEnumerable`.

**EDIT**: Based on comment...

> But I want to display just the various types of pest (Dog, Cat, etc)
>   not all the pests that are in my database

OK, are these categorised, could you write something like (hand written so check syntax)..

```
var pests = (from _context.Pests.Where(p => p.CategoryId == 1) select p.PestName).ToList();
```

If you need to get a IEnumerable for the enum (since I'm not sure what the DB looks like), you can use...

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(PestType))
            .OfType<PestType>()
            .Where(p => p == ??);
```

Comment: But I want to display just the various types of pest (Dog, Cat, etc) not all the pests that are in my database

Comment: @lucaConfa, you can tell I'm tired, I thought the type was `PetType`, I've changed the answer to use `Pest` now :)

Comment: @christandev don't worry I guessed what you meant to do! Thanx!!

Comment: I am a bit confused by this answer as the first part seems incorrect. `Html.DropDownList` also has an override which takes just the name and a default string label (to display when no option is selected). `"PestType"` would then be used as a key to find a `SelectList` in a PestType property on the view model, or failing that it will look for `ViewData["PestType"]` for the list. The error seems to be simply down to not populating a`PestType` property anywhere (which you did cover).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, are you saying the answer above the edit can be removed?

Comment: I have posted the simple solution below. All the answers so far avoided the simplest approach (which hardly modifies the original code).

Answer (score 4):

Currently your model only contains a place to store the value and not a Array/IEnumerable to populate the drop down from.

First add an IEnumerable to your model:

```
public class SinglePest
{
    public int SinglePestId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PestType> Pests { get; set; }
    public PestType PestType { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string  TechName { get; set; }
    public string Markings { get; set; }

    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public SourceType SourceType { get; set; }

    //virtual property
    public Source Source { get; set; }
}
```

And in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{    
    var model = new SinglePest();

    model.Pests = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PestType)).Cast<PestType>()

    return View(model);
}
```

And your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PestType, Model.Pests);
```

Sorry if theres any errors I've written this from memory...

Comment: I have noticed that your solution and the one I have found are very similar. Basically they are doing the same thing. Any idea which is better to implement and why? (I am a bit concerning in adding another property in my model as it will affect my database as well)

Comment: Because your using the Enum value it wont go to the database, unless your then querying to get more details?  Remember your Model isn't actually being sent down to the client's PC its just for generating the HTML on the server.  Premature Optimization is not a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

I found this post on [DropDownListFor enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656758/mvc3-razor-dropdownlistfor-enums)
It seems it is solving my problem.

so I have just changed the view with this new piece of code:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PestType, "Pest Type")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PestType, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof( MvcTrackingSystem.Enums.PestType))))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PestType)
    </div>
```

Now it looks like it is working

On the difference between `DropDownList` and `DropDownListFor` I have found useful infromation [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182280/difference-between-dropdownlist-or-dropdownlistfor-html-helper)

Comment: Yes, this is the correct method for a list on a strongly typed object in the view, but I would still do the list creation in the controller so you have more control (no pun intended) over the content (and filtering you may add) and the selected value. Simple example answer added for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the original problem quite simply with this in your `GET` Create method:

```
ViewBag.PestType = new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(PestType)).OfType<PestType>());
```

and this in your POST Create method (where validation fails and it returns the view):

```
ViewBag.PestType = new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(PestType)).OfType<PestType>(),
                                  singlepest.PestType);
```

if you want to keep it strongly typed in the view use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PestType, ViewBag.PestType as SelectList)
```

If you don't mind the weak typed version use the simpler:

```
@Html.DropDownList("PestType")
```

In either case I suggest you create all lists in the controller and not in the view.

### Explanation:

Basically `DropDownlist` will search the `ViewData` (i.e. your `ViewBag` settings) for a list of options for the member of the same name (if a list is not explicitly provided).

I mocked up the whole project (MVC5/VS2013) and more of the code is below for your reference.

### Controller:

```
using PestTypeTest.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace PestTypeTest.Controllers
{
    public class PestTypeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /PestType/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.PestType = new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(PestType)).OfType<PestType>());
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(//(SinglePest singlepest)
        [Bind(Include = "Alias, TechName, SerialNumber, PestType, Markings")] SinglePest singlepest)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    //db.SinglePests.Add(singlepest);
                    //db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (DataException /* dex */)
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes, try again, if problem   persits contact your administrator");
            }

            //ViewBag.SerialNumber = new SelectList(db.Sources, "SerialNumber", "SerialNumber", singlepest.SerialNumber);
            ViewBag.PestType = new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(PestType)).OfType<PestType>(), singlepest.PestType);
            return View(singlepest);
        }
    }
}
```

### Views\PestType\Create.cshtml

```
@model PestTypeTest.Models.SinglePest

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>SinglePest</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PestType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("PestType")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PestType)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Alias, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Alias)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Alias)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TechName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TechName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TechName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Markings, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Markings)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Markings)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SerialNumber, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SerialNumber)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SerialNumber)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```