# maintain state in a mvc drop down

Tags: model-view-controller

I have the following code and when I update, I get the correct results out of a list of dropdowns. I.E.. if I update one of the list items to "Closed" it does exactly what it is told both in the view and the database.

But as soon as I move away from the view and then come back, I lose the "state". Is there a way I can add a "Selected" to this of do I need to re-think?

```
@{
    var listItems = new List<ListItem> {
    new ListItem {Text = "Open", Value = "Open"},
    new ListItem {Text = "Closed", Value = "Closed"},
    new ListItem {Text = "Standby", Value = "Standby"}};
}
@Html.DropDownList("Parks[" + (@i + 10) + "].ParkStatus", new SelectList(listItems), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Edit**

I think I need some kind of **"Is Selected"** in the following string?

```
@Html.DropDownList("Parks[" + (@i + 10) + "].ParkStatus", new SelectList(listItems), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out and I was on the right track, it was a need for extra parameters in:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Parks[" + (@i + 10) + "].ParkStatus", new SelectList(listItems), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

It now looks like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Parks[" + (@i + 10) + "].ParkStatus", new SelectList(listItems, "Text", "Value", Model[i].ParkStatus), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

And is working great.

Thanks for you help ste-fu you helped point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@Html.DropDownListFor` - see this question [Difference between DropDownlist or DropDownListFor Html helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182280/difference-between-dropdownlist-or-dropdownlistfor-html-helper)

Comment: but that is not what I need here!

Comment: How about this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624828/asp-net-mvc-html-dropdownlist-selectedvalue